# Integration openstack &opendaylight

Tags: python, openstack, openflow, opendaylight

**strong text**i need your help , i would like to do intergartion between openstack liberty(devstack) and opendaylight Beryllium.  some one who know whow?  i check lot of in internet but always the same documentation .

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well, you could consult the OPNFV (Open Platform for Network Function Virtualization) project.  OPNFV builds an integrated release of OpenStack with OpenDaylight as the SDN controller.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this blog on [Openstack(kilo) integration with Opendaylight(Lithium)](http://www.cloudenablers.com/blog/opendaylight-integration-with-openstack/)
This would help you through the steps on deploying OpenDaylight and integrating it with Openstack to address use case specific to networking infrastructure.

Comment: Think you , i take note